# How to bypass ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Lost connection to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I got a situation here.

I want to keep site up when MySQL server is down (my site should run when DB server 'mysql' is down)

I am using MySql2 gem with activerecord 4.0.0.

As far i know i need to write out a middleware that will check whether the DB server is up, if DB server is up then we are fine, but if DB server is down then we just need to bypass DB transaction request and render page/call(need to catch MYSQL error Lost Connection exception).

I know there are multiple gems like:

- https://github.com/bdurand/seamless_database_pool 'seamless_database_pool'
- https://github.com/schoefmax/multi_db 'multi_db'
- https://github.com/taskrabbit/makara 'makara'

All these gems supports master/slave DB concept/architecture, where as i don't want to use master-slave db architecture.

So i had simply created a file in config/initializer/database_timeout.rb and it looks like below.

```
module Mysql2
  class Client
    def initialize(opts = {})
      opts = Mysql2::Util.key_hash_as_symbols( opts )
      @read_timeout = nil
      @query_options = @@default_query_options.dup
      @query_options.merge! opts

      initialize_ext

      [:reconnect, :connect_timeout, :local_infile, :read_timeout, :write_timeout, :default_file, :default_group, :secure_auth].each do |key|
        next unless opts.key?(key)
        case key
        when :reconnect, :local_infile, :secure_auth
          send(:"#{key}=", !!opts[key])
        when :connect_timeout, :read_timeout, :write_timeout
          send(:"#{key}=", opts[key].to_i)
        else
          send(:"#{key}=", opts[key])
        end
      end

      # force the encoding to utf8
      self.charset_name = opts[:encoding] || 'utf8'

      ssl_options = opts.values_at(:sslkey, :sslcert, :sslca, :sslcapath, :sslcipher)
      ssl_set(*ssl_options) if ssl_options.any?

      if [:user,:pass,:hostname,:dbname,:db,:sock].any?{|k| @query_options.has_key?(k) }
        warn "============= WARNING FROM mysql2 ============="
        warn "The options :user, :pass, :hostname, :dbname, :db, and :sock will be deprecated at some point in the future."
        warn "Instead, please use :username, :password, :host, :port, :database, :socket, :flags for the options."
        warn "============= END WARNING FROM mysql2 ========="
      end

      user     = opts[:username] || opts[:user]
      pass     = opts[:password] || opts[:pass]
      host     = opts[:host] || opts[:hostname]
      port     = opts[:port]
      database = opts[:database] || opts[:dbname] || opts[:db]
      socket   = opts[:socket] || opts[:sock]
      flags    = opts[:flags] ? opts[:flags] | @query_options[:connect_flags] : @query_options[:connect_flags]

      # Correct the data types before passing these values down to the C level
      user = user.to_s unless user.nil?
      pass = pass.to_s unless pass.nil?
      host = host.to_s unless host.nil?
      port = port.to_i unless port.nil?
      database = database.to_s unless database.nil?
      socket = socket.to_s unless socket.nil?

      begin
        connect user, pass, host, port, database, socket, flags
      rescue StandardError => err
        p 'sssssss'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I am getting following error in 'err' variable, which means i can successfully get the error exception. Notice this message come up while hitting to my website.

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

After above block server is throwing me following error

```
[2014-01-10T18:11:16.080922 #16264]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-10 18:11:16 +0500
"sssssss"
"sssssss"
F, [2014-01-10T18:13:53.570439 #16264] FATAL -- : 
Mysql2::Error (closed MySQL connection):
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:77:in `escape'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:77:in `quote_string'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb:15:in `quote'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:246:in `quote'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:772:in `block in configure_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:768:in `each'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:768:in `map'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:768:in `configure_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:265:in `configure_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:38:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:20:in `new'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:20:in `mysql2_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
  /home/sannankhalid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
  /home/sannankhalid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__4494376046790926309__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.14) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  /home/sannankhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@astrology-site/bundler/gems/astro_logger-d53871b98caa/lib/astro_logger/middlewares/finish_logging.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  airbrake (3.1.14) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (3.1.14) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `require'
  bin/rails:4:in `<top (required)>'
  ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22) lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_load'
  ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22) lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:86:in `debug_program'
  ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22) bin/rdebug-ide:110:in `<top (required)>'
  -e:1:in `load'
  -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Is there any work around? or how should i approach to overcome my needs!

Help really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: it there not an error 500 in production mode running?

Comment: thats fine. so why not handling the error from your webserver?

Comment: I need to make site working when mysql is down, for handling MYSQL CONNECTION LOST exception i need to first override default behaviour of MySql2 gem according to my need. For this i had added a new file as i mentioned above.

Comment: any update on this? Don't tell me i have asked stupid question.. There must be some work around!